# Importing a Text File into a MySQL through Navicat DB software

Tags: mysql, text, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a Text File into a MySQL through Navicat DB software.

I am struggling to import(append) a text file into a MySQL table. 
The text file fields are seperated by | ;

example : |Name|Email|Address|

When i import this through the Navicat import wizard it ask for " Which delimeter seperates
the fields. So instead of selecting Tabs, ; , or any other i select | as field seperator.

But still the fields in the file do not match(sync) with the fields  of the table...

Can anyone suggest any advice here?

I actually have exported the text file from another MySQL DB thru export functionality from PHPMyAdmin,,

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `name` column is null and the values appear instead in the `email` column?

I suspect the problem lies in the fact that your fields are not only *separated* by a pipe, your rows also *begin and end* with a pipe.

Think of a CSV: `name,email,address`, not `,name,email,address,`, because that would be interpreted as 5 columns, the value of the first and last field being null.

Comment: Ok i get it..but so what do i have to put in the delimeter as? If it was XML file what would be the delimetere seperated as ? column, table,?

Comment: If you have access to the original database and are importing the data into another database, why not re-export it as SQL?

Comment: ok i found the solution..instead of exporting the database from PHPmyAdmin from another database i exported it through navicat software ..text file with delimeter as TAB and then again i imported into the new database again with navicat...so it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to choose a different delimiter for your rows and fields.

Beyond that, you can try importing the data into a new table and then write an insert query to map the temp fields to the ones in your database.  The screen after the one where you choose the target table has a table where you can map your import fields to the target ones.

[image: Navicat Import - Field Mappings Screen]

Let me know how that works out.